# eclipse maven filename specification

Tags: eclipse, maven, filenames

How to configure maven build in eclipse to use another filename?

Analog of:

```
mvn -f custom_pom_name.pom


mvn --help
...
-f,--file                              Force the use of an alternate POM
                                   file.
...
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that, cause it's against the conventions. The question is why do you need such a thing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `-f custom_pom_name.pom` to the `Goals:` section in the run configuration dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Choose `Run As` -> `Maven build...`. In the dialog add `f` as parameter with the pom-File as value.

... or consider using profiles instead of different pom-files.

Comment: Strange. I input parameter name-value pair as "f pom2.xml" but after save and reopen of configuration parameter value dissappears.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the file name disappearing.  Just settled on running it from the command line for now.

Answer (score 0):

set the `finalName` property in pom.xml as follows:

```
 <build>
   <finalName>myjar</finalName>
 </build>
```

From commandline: We cannot directly override `fileName`. Adding the following property in pom, we can do as follows:

```
<myCustomName>${artifactId}-${version}</myCustomName>
....
<build>
<finalName>${myCustomName}</finalName>
...
</build>
```

from commandline, we can define as follows:

```
-DmyCustomName=%maven.project.artifcatId%-%build.number%
```